# Sort sequelize.js query by date

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

```
Post
  .findAll({where: {tag: 'news'}, limit: 10})
  .success(function(result) { ... })
```

How to insert the condition of sorting by date in my query with not using `sequelize.query` like

```
.findAll({ limit: 10, sort: [updatedAt, descending]})
```

Answer (score 151, accepted):

@dankohn is correct and that will work but it is safer to use the following:

```
Post.findAll({ limit: 10, order: [['updatedAt', 'DESC']]});
```

as this

> will escape updatedAt and validate DESC against a list of valid direction parameters

Comment: Correct answer, selected answer is deprecated.

Comment: This one worked like a charm! Selected one is deprecaated.

Comment: Can we apply the order on the basis of does value exist in the `JOIN` in sequelize.
What I want is that for entries for which associated items are not there they should come in the last place.

Answer (score 27):

Here's the syntax:

```
Post.findAll({ limit: 10, order: '"updatedAt" DESC' })
```

Here are more [examples](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/querying/#ordering) from the official documentation.

Comment: Appears to no longer work in newer versions of Sequelize (I'm using 4.4), but Clarkie's answer worked.  The error message I received from this method seems to indicate that it was deprecated: "Unhandled rejection Error: Order must be type of array or instance of a valid sequelize method."

Comment: Not sure that is a good way to delete answer, maybe it's better that you custom mod flag, explaining why it should be deleted, since also after Clarkie's answer needs an edit.

Comment: Deprecated. `Unhandled rejection Error: Order must be type of array or instance of a valid sequelize method.`

Comment: @Sandwich Should be like `Post.findAll({ limit: 10, order: [ ['updatedAt',  'DESC'] ] })` in new versions. Edit: did not see last response.

Comment: OP please update to show which version your answer is correct for. I have Sequelize version 6.0.0 which requires the array ["FIELD", "ASC"] be nested inside another array as described by @Clarkie

Comment: my god sequelize has a really terrible API.

Answer (score 2):

Following is more cleaner syntax

`Post.findAll({ limit: 10, order: 'updatedAt DESC'});`

Comment: Sequelize 5.21 will throw that order type must be an array.

Comment: Cannot be used in ealier versions of sequelize

Comment: Your answer is working fine. But now it was deprecated and will generate Order must be the type of array or instance of a valid sequelize method. error